# how to get the pajama effect with New-Object -com Excel.Application

Tags: worksheet-function, powershell

Does anyone know how to get this effect? Or is there a specific function for it?

[image]

Comment: Format Table? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me:

```
$ListObject = $x.ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType]::xlSrcRange, $x.ActiveCell.CurrentRegion, $null ,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess]::xlYes)
$ListObject.Name = "name-table"
$ListObject.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2"
```